# What is .NET Core Shared Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

As far as I am concerned, referencing individual ASP.NET Core NuGet packages are somewhat discouraged since 2.1/2.2 the shared framework on .NET Core should be used instead. I use Rider on MacOS and when I create a new project, I am not able to see AspNetCore.StaticFiles or EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. I don't understand how to have these references without using NuGet. How can I use shared framework for achieving this issue?

Comment: A quick search of your question title found [this article, explaining what the ASP.NET Core Shared Framework is](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-shared-framework-in-asp-net-core-2-1-preview-1/). You can't use the shared framework for libraries that are not part of the framework. So, for instance, Entity Framework will need to be referenced a different way.

Comment: good point. StaticFiles is part of the Framework though but somehow I still can not see any other option except adding through NuGet.

Comment: @HereticMonkey [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App includes EF core now.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2)  This sounds like it might be a Rider issue to me; JetBrains opted not to adopt Roslyn and other common tools, and I've noticed they haven't been able to keep up with .NET Core lately.  Any issues I've reported to them were never resolved or took months to resolve.

Comment: What kind of new project do you want to create? That really determines how you then add references to the shared framework.

Comment: @LexLi I use empty Asp.Net Core app as I used to create in Windows and I have never had any of these issues on Visual Studio.